# gb4e and leipzig not working together: TeX capacity exceeded

Tags: miktex, linguistics, gb4e, capacity, leipzig

I'm on Windows 11 using MikTex as my LaTeX manager. I'm trying to make good-looking linguistic glosses using `gb4e` and `leipzig`, but they don't seem to be compatible together for some reason on my platform for some reason. This example from [this article](https://cipanglo.hypotheses.org/1221) that I'm following doesn't work:

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{gb4e}
\usepackage{leipzig}

\begin{document}

% Empty document environment

\end{document}
```

The Errors:

```
C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex\latex\fp\fp-eval.sty|72 error| TeX capacity exceeded, sor
C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex\latex\fp\fp-eval.sty|72 error| ==> Fatal error occurred,
```

What's going wrong here? I haven't found anything online about incompatibility between these packages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`gb4e` is incompatible with many other packages.

The problem here seems to be in the `\automath` setting. Change the loading order.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{leipzig}
\usepackage{gb4e}

\begin{document}

% Empty document environment

\end{document}
```

Comment: Did you edit your answer? I think I noticed before that there was a line that said `\noautomath`. If so, why did you change it?

Comment: @Mailbox I realized that just changing the loading order was enough. Add `\noautomath`  if you find it necessary.